# How to store entire Google maps route in DB?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to store entire route path in the Database, so that whenever I want exactly I will show the route, now what is happening is I'm storing only source, destination but Google maps is not giving me the expected route, it is giving me the shortest route.

I want my route to show on Google maps. Please tell me how to do this.

I am using Google maps API Javascript v2.

Comment: Is it still against the terms of service? Is there a workaround to store this data? How does Nike do it?

Answer (score 1):

That will be against the Terms of Service.

Comment: Is it still against the terms of service? I see that Nike and Uber do it. How does that work?